# pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "myip"

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, database-administration

There are many questions regarding this matter but, I did the said solutions came from other topic like adding my IP to the `pg_hba.conf`. Please see the images:

[Error Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvAMW.png)
[pg_hba config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh7PV.png)

**Information:** I'm accessing an appliance database with the correct user, password, dbname (because it is on their document).

However, after I configure my IP to the `pg_hba.conf` I did restart PostgreSQL on `services.msc` but the error still there.

I had already restarted my PC but the error still there.

What should I do?

Comment: check   listen_address = '*" and port =      properly restart service and also mention IP address of client in postgres server under pg_hba.conf

Comment: my listen_address is * and port is 5432. still i cant connect . i also put the client and the server ip in pg_hba.conf . still icant connect

Answer (score 0):

Your pg_hba file seems to be on point, and you said that you had restarted the postgres service.

May I ask, which postgres service did you restart? The server's or the client's?

The pg_hba file is a server config. Therefore, the server must be restarted for it to take effect.

Comment: I restart the server. the service name is "postgresql-x64-9.5 - PostgreSQL Server 9.5"

Answer (score 0):

You can check hba_file value in postgresql.conf if you have specified separately and try to reload the configuration... Also check you have correct entry of IP.

Database server restarted successfully it means you have no configuration errors.

Answer (score 0):

I hope help with my case. (I know this is an old case)

Couple a weeks ago I faced same error but was weird 'cause I had been working well for severals months.
After do double checks a realize all config was ok, I read a post with a warning.
And that was we were hacked and attacker added these 3 lines before all comments in the pg_hba.conf file.

- host all myowndb 0.0.0.0/0 reject
- host all postgres 0.0.0.0/0 reject
- host all pgdbadm 0.0.0.0/0 md5

after delete first two lines, all connections were possible.
Obviously security team in my company was alerted and vulnerability scan was performed to discard some other damages.